# ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 429├ù20 ArrayLogical{2} at index [430, Base.Slice(Base.OneTo(20))] running Julia script

Tags: csv, julia

I am trying to run a julia script on 4 csv files. But I keep getting this error:

```
samde@DESKTOP-V6PBDGC MINGW64 ~/mimix (master)
$ C:/Users/samde/AppData/Local/Programs/Julia/Julia-1.4.2/bin/julia.exe scripts/fit-mcmc.jl --hyper nutnet-analysis/configs/hyper.yml --monitor nutnet-analysis/configs/monitor-mimix.yml --inits nutnet-analysis/configs/inits.yml --factors 20 nutnet-analysis/test-data samnutnet-results
Reading X.csv
Reading Y.csv
Reading Z.csv
Beginning MCMC sampling
ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 429├ù20 ArrayLogical{2} at index [430, Base.Slice(Base.OneTo(20))]
Stacktrace:
 [1] throw_boundserror(::ArrayLogical{2}, ::Tuple{Int64,Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}) at .\abstractarray.jl:537
 [2] checkbounds at .\abstractarray.jl:502 [inlined]
 [3] _getindex at .\multidimensional.jl:726 [inlined]
 [4] getindex at .\abstractarray.jl:980 [inlined]
 [5] (::MicrobiomeMixedModels.var"#14#63")(::ArrayLogical{2}, ::Int64) at C:\Users\samde\mimix\MicrobiomeMixedModels.jl\src\models\mimix.jl:109
 [6] (::var"#36#37")(::Model) at .\array.jl:0
 [7] setinits!(::ArrayStochastic{2}, ::Model, ::Array{Float64,2}) at C:\Users\samde\.julia\packages\Mamba\PkMTm\src\model\dependent.jl:173
 [8] setinits!(::Model, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}) at C:\Users\samde\.julia\packages\Mamba\PkMTm\src\model\initialization.jl:11
 [9] setinits!(::Model, ::Array{Dict{Symbol,Any},1}) at C:\Users\samde\.julia\packages\Mamba\PkMTm\src\model\initialization.jl:24
 [10] mcmc(::Model, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Array{Dict{Symbol,Any},1}, ::Int64; burnin::Int64, thin::Int64, chains::Int64, verbose::Bool) at C:\Users\samde\.julia\packages\Mamba\PkMTm\src\model\mcmc.jl:30
 [11] top-level scope at C:\Users\samde\mimix\scripts\fit-mcmc.jl:150
 [12] include(::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:377
 [13] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:288
 [14] _start() at .\client.jl:484
in expression starting at C:\Users\samde\mimix\scripts\fit-mcmc.jl:105
```

I have tried deleting the last lines in every csv file. I tried saving as normal CSV files and CSV UTF-8 files. Running wc -l shows them all to be at the same lengths. I have looked at similar questions but have had trouble understanding the solutions. Any idea what could fix this error?

Here are the files: https://github.com/samd1993/mimixtest.git

The code works on the sample files found here: https://github.com/nsgrantham/mimix/tree/master/nutnet-analysis/reduced-data

@mbauman here is the code for mimix.jl at line 109:

108  F = Stochastic(2,

**109            (F_mean, N) -> MultivariateDistribution[**

110                MvNormal(F_mean[i, :], 1.0) for i in 1:N

111            ],
false

Thank you,
Sam

Comment: what's happening in `MicrobiomeMixedModels.jl\src\models\mimix.jl:109`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will post above so you can see the code above and below line 109

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own problem with the help of @mbauman's hint. The error was occurring due to my csv files not having the same dimensions. Thus, if anyone runs into this issue, make sure your data files are intact and there aren't any extra columns or rows. Rudimentary...but important.
Cheers,
Sam